# Suspend/awakening computer in Chrome loses video camera feed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

When showing a camera feed through a `<video>` tag, I observe different behavior between Firefox and Chrome when suspending the operating system (i.e. closing/clamshelling the laptop on my Macbook). Afterwards, when resuming the OS:

- on Firefox, the camera feed is immediately re-established
- on Chrome, the camera feed goes black

As an aside, I've also noticed that the [suspend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/suspend_event) event behaves differently:

- on Firefox, it is sent when the camera feed is first connected to the video tag (i.e. nothing to do with OS suspend/resume, as far as I can tell)
- on Chrome, it is sent when the OS resumes (i.e. after re-opening the laptop)

I'd like to have Chrome match Firefox's behavior, i.e. show the video feed after resuming from a suspend situation. Is this possible?

Comment: sounds more like a camera/Chrome bug

Comment: the `ended` event should fire on the MediaStreamtrack, no?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand the underlying difference between browsers, I have a workaround:

Ignore any "suspend" event if it happens immediately after the video component is mounted. However, if a "suspend" event is received thereafter, do the following:

1. Wait at least 2 seconds (any sooner and it seems an error will occur when re-querying for permission; another strategy could be to "keep trying" until success)
2. Re-query for permission to use the camera/audio (Chrome will automatically grant it)
3. Re-mount the video & audio tags, and establish a video stream again.

The camera stream will show in the video tag again.